# Flutter I can't release or debug when I add Connectivity

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, connectivity, flutter-animation

**SOLUTION for this problem**
I deleted the JDK 13. I installed JDK 8.
I gave the environment variable for the Flutter SDK. in user variables
flutter
C: \ flutter \ bin

I gave the environment variable for JAVA_HOME. in system variables
JAVA_HOME
C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.8.0_241

Then I accepted Android licenses with cmd.
(flutter doctor --android-licenses)

Now I can use flutter connectivity.
The problem is solved. Thank you.

**-------------------------------------------------**

I cannot debug or release to my app when I add Connectivity to my app's pubspec.yaml

Flutter Doctor

```
[flutter] flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.657], locale tr-TR)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (9 days ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Faruk Aydin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[!] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[√] VS Code (version 1.42.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Faruk Aydin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.8.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Redmi 8A • f12007c00606 • android-arm • Android 9 (API 28)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
exit code 0
```

Comment: you have to accept the android licenses.

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: use this command flutter doctor --android-licenses

Comment: ı did it. But I am getting this message "'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: add flutter sdk path in environmental variable.

Comment: okay so add flutter as global variable

Comment: I deleted the JDK 13. I installed JDK 8.
I gave the environment variable for the Flutter SDK. in user variables
flutter
C: \ flutter \ bin

I gave the environment variable for JAVA_HOME. in system variables
JAVA_HOME
C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.8.0_241

Then I accepted Android licenses with cmd.
(flutter doctor --android-licenses)

Now I can use flutter connectivity.
The problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the JDK 13. I installed JDK 8.

I gave the environment variable for the Flutter SDK. in user variables
flutter
C: \ flutter \ bin

I gave the environment variable for JAVA_HOME. in system variables
JAVA_HOME
C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.8.0_241

Then I accepted Android licenses with cmd.
(flutter doctor --android-licenses)

Now I can use flutter connectivity.
The problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a global file under your username in Mac. Just create a .bashprofile file as described bellow:

[Open to see location and locate your flutter sdk inside.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyZyi.png)

Comment: I deleted the JDK 13. I installed JDK 8.
I gave the environment variable for the Flutter SDK. in user variables
flutter
C: \ flutter \ bin

I gave the environment variable for JAVA_HOME. in system variables
JAVA_HOME
C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.8.0_241

Then I accepted Android licenses with cmd.
(flutter doctor --android-licenses)

Now I can use flutter connectivity.
The problem is solved. Thank you.

Comment: You are most welcome @FarukAYDIN . If my answer helped you can caste vote as answer so others also can get help. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am using Windows 10. I just wanted said I solved this problem. 
And I accept a comment for solution.
here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60322556/12716244
Thank you